# onDeviceReady not firing in Cordova Windows 10 app only in Release mode

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, uwp, sencha-touch, windows-10-universal

I have a Sencha Touch app which worked without issues until the Windows 10 Anniversary update is launched. With the new SDK, my app's onDeviceReady event is not fired after I build the store packages. **But it works perfectly in debug mode**.

I believe this has something to do with the .NET Native Tool Chain. But I am still lost after 3 days of troubleshooting and lots and lots of Googling. Here's what I have tried already:

- Re-generated Sencha Touch app using latest Sencha CMD version.
- Removed and added latest versions of cordova, platforms, and plugins from scratch.
- Kept the index.html file as minimal as possible to see if it is something to do with the code in this file.

Below is the list of plugins I have installed.

```
com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin 2.5.0 "PushPlugin"
com.verso.cordova.clipboard 0.1.0 "Clipboard"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.3.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-contacts 2.2.0 "Contacts"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-device-orientation 1.0.4 "Device Orientation"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.5.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-media 2.4.0 "Media"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.0 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 1.4.2 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"
cordova-sms-plugin 0.1.11 "Cordova SMS Plugin"
cordova.plugins.navbar 1.0.0 "NavBar"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.9.0 "PushPlugin"
```

I had a doubt if the body onload event is not getting fired. Therefore, I called `onLoad()` function inside the script tag inside html body also. No luck.

**index.html body**

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <div id="appLoadingIndicator"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        onLoad();
        var apploading = document.getElementById('appLoadingIndicator');
        apploading.style.lineHeight = document.body.clientHeight + 'px';
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute('src', resourceURL + '/loading/logo-splash.png');
        apploading.appendChild(img);
    </script>
</body>
```

**onLoad function definition**

```
function onLoad() {
    console.log('xxxxxx addEventListener onDeviceReady');
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", onDeviceResume, false);
}
```

Has anyone come across any similar issues? Any hint on this will be very helpful.

Comment: Could you please try it with a blank Cordova or Sencha Touch App?

Comment: A blank app works without issues. This is a considerably large app which is already in the stores for 2+ years. Anyway, I have solved it. I will post it as an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the onDeviceReady was actually firing, but only after 5+ seconds. Sencha Touch app was loading before the onDeviceReady is fired and the app was accessing `device` object during launch, which was `undefined`. This caused the app to crash. Therefore, triggering app launch inside the onDeviceReady handler did the trick.

**onDeviceReady() in index.html**

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    if (Ext.os.is.Phone) {
        myApp.app.launchPhone();
    } else {
        myApp.app.launchTablet();
    }
    ...
}
```

**launch() in app.js**

```
launch: function() {
   // left empty intentionally
}
```